Ubuntu 24.10 No Sound From Speakers or Ethernet Cable Detection MSI Laptop
I am a Linux n00b and recently got an MSI Stealth A16 laptop. It has an Nvidia 4070 GeForce graphics card (which as I have come to learn doesn't always play well with Linux). My laptop doesn't play any audio, nor does the laptop recognize ethernet connection. I had Ubuntu 24.04 LTS before, but 24.04 LTS didn't support the WiFi 7 module the laptop has, therefore I updated to 24.10. The WiFi works now, but ethernet and sound do not. I have tried alsamixer, pulseaudio, that the drivers are present, and yes--checking that I am not on mute. Can someone point me in the right direction for solving these issues?
Some specs:
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   20
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-19
Vendor ID:                AuthenticAMD
  Model name:             AMD Ryzen AI 9 365 w/ Radeon 880M
    CPU family:           26
    Model:                36

Kernel version
uname -r
6.11.0-9-generic

Audio:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC274 Analog [ALC274 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


Audio driver info:
lspci | grep -i audio
c3:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation AD106M High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
c5:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
c5:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 70)
c5:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller

Thank you for your help!
